# How can i align a <li> center when its inside of <ul> and inside of a <nav>

Tags: html, css

I would like to align my `<li>` center about the `<nav>` how can i do it ?

There is the code :

.html

```
<nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

.css

```
.nav {
    border: 2px solid;
}

.nav ul li{
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set `text-align: center` on `nav` and remove `padding-left` on `ul`

```css
.nav {
  border: 2px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.nav ul li {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```